# problema con menú switch en c#

Tags: c#

tengo este código en c# que se trata de dos ejercicios separados en dos clases, la clase promedios y la clase arreglo. mi pregunta es como hago un menú que le permita al usuario elegir que ejercicio desea realizar y ejecute el contenido de la clase que contiene el proceso de respuesta.
muchas gracias

Clase Arreglos:

```
namespace tallerarray
{

}
    class arreglos
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
           Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, porfavor elija una opcion" +
          "\n 1.Generar un arreglo." +
          "\n 2.promediar notas." +
          "\n 3.consultar los numeros pares e impares de entre 7 numeros." +
          "\n 4.Salir.\n");
            int opcion = 0;
            Console.ReadKey();
            switch (opcion)
            { 
                case 1:
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write("Se ingreso una accion inesistente");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;

                    {

                    }
                }
        }
    }

        private int[] vec;

        public void Cargar()
        {
            vec = new int[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("porfavor ingrese un numero:");
                string linea;
                linea = Console.ReadLine();/* aca recolecta el dato ingresado*/
                vec[i] = int.Parse(linea);
            }
        }

        public void AcumularElementos()/*suma de los 8 elementos*/
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                suma = suma + vec[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("La suma de los 8 elementos es:" + suma);
        }


        public void AcumularMayores23_45()/*suma los numeros mayores a 23 y menores de 45*/
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (vec[i] > 23 & vec[i] <= 45)  
         /*coloque un rango entre 23 y 45 tal como comprendi el enunciado
        */
                {
                    suma = suma + vec[i];      
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("La suma de los elementos mayores a 23 y menores de 45 es:" + suma);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        }
```

Clase Promedios:

```
public class Promedios
{

        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Promedios pv = new Promedios(); /* al igual que en el primero coloque dos public void fuera de la clase y los llame aca,
            eh intentado hacer las notas del curso a en un public void diferente del curso b 
            pero me salian muchos herrores y eh preferido hacerlo de esta forma*/
            pv.Cargar();
            pv.CalcularPromedios();
        }
        private int[] cursoa;
        private int[] cursob;

        public void Cargar()
        {
            cursoa = new int[7];/* defino que cada curso cuenta con 7 estudiantes*/
            cursob = new int[7];
            Console.WriteLine("notas del curso A");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese la nota de el estudiante:");
                string linea;
                linea = Console.ReadLine();
                cursoa[i] = int.Parse(linea);                         
            /*utilize un for para cada uno de los cursos el A y el B*/
            }
            Console.WriteLine("notas del curso B");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese la nota del estudiante:");
                string linea;
                linea = Console.ReadLine();/*aqui se recoje el dato ingresado*/
                cursob[i] = int.Parse(linea);
            }
        }

        public void CalcularPromedios()/* calculo de los promedios*/
        {
            int suma1 = 0;
            int suma2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                suma1 = suma1 + cursoa[i];
                suma2 = suma2 + cursob[i];
            }
            int promedioa = suma1 / 7;
            int promediob = suma2 / 7;
            if (promedioa > promediob)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El curso A tiene un promedio mayor.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El curso B tiene un promedio mayor.");
                /*aca se comparan los resultados de la sumas y las diviciones entre la cantidad de notas (7),
                luego use un if-else para determinar el curso con mayor promedio*/
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }     
    }
```

Comment: Una aplicación solo debería tener un método `main`. Lo que debes hacer es tener una tercera clase con su método `main` que sea la que se inicie al arrancar la aplicación. Desde ella es donde debes instanciar la clase `arreglos` o `promedios` dependiendo de la entrada del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tallerarray
{

```
class Arreglos
{
    private static List<int> notas= notas = new List<int>();
    public Arreglos()
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, porfavor elija una opcion" +
                               "\n 1.Generar un arreglo." +
                               "\n 2.promediar notas." +
                               "\n 3.consultar los numeros pares e impares de entre 7 numeros." +
                               "\n 4.Salir.\n");

            int opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    GenerarArray();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("promedio: "+Promediar());
                    Console.WriteLine("pulsa alguna tecla para seguir...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ConsultarParImpar();
                    Console.WriteLine("pulsa alguna tecla para seguir...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }


    }



    public static void GenerarArray()
    {
        char op = ' ';
        while (op != 'n')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Añade los datos:");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            notas.Add(n);
            Console.WriteLine("Quieres seguir añadiendo datos? s/n");
            op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        }

    }

    public static double Promediar()
    {
        double promedio = 0;
        int nota = 0;
        foreach (int n in notas)
        {

            nota += n;
        }
        promedio = nota / notas.Count;
        return promedio;
    }

    public static void ConsultarParImpar()
    {
        foreach (int n in notas)
        {
            if (n % 2 != 0) Console.WriteLine(n + " impar");
            else Console.WriteLine(n + " par");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Saludos @chunying11! Gracias por interesarte en aportar tu conocimiento a la comunidad respondiendo a las preguntas. Esta respuesta carece de contenido y solo publica la solución al problema sin explicar como dar con la solución, pasate por [answer] para que sepas cuál es el formato de una respuesta bien elaborada y editas la respuesta para cumplir con ese formato, así personas con este problema en un futuro no copian solo tu código sin entender lo que hace :)